# Memory consumption of ASP.Net app

Tags: iis-7.5, asp.net, .net, memory-usage, memory-leak

I'm migrating an existing ASP.Net (MVC3) application to a new server. The primary reason is to migrate to IIS 7.5/Windows 2008 while it's currently on IIS 6/Windows 2003.

The new server has 8GB of memory while the current production has only 2GB. The application typically settles in around 500MB of memory under load in current production. (No sign of memory leaks running in production for more than 2 years)

However during load testing of the app on the new environment, I noticed that it's consuming memory quite aggressively. After leaving the app for 3-4 hours under load the relevant w3wp.exe has 2GB of memory allocated to it. (I have not put in memory restriction on the app pool - which is the case in current production as well).

I have done several tests and all point me in the direction of .Net CLR doing eager allocation of memory. However I can't find any solid proof/documentation from Microsoft.

Can someone please shed some more light on this issue preferably with some references to this aggressive memory allocation by CLR?

Kind Regards,
Uchitha.